# Expected a value of type 'List<int>', but got one of type 'WhereIterable<int>'

Tags: dart

```dart
List<int> filterEvens(List<int> ints) {
  var foo = ints.where((n) => n.isEven) as List<int>;
  var bar = ints.where((n) => n.isEven).toList();

  return foo; // Runtime error
  // return bar; // Works
}

void main() {
  print(filterEvens([1]));
}
```

When I am explicitly downcasting `Iterable` to `List` in the 1st line of above function, it throws an error:

> Error: Expected a value of type 'List', but got one of type 'WhereIterable'

Comment: `WhereIterable` is not a `List` so it makes sense you get an error?

Comment: @julemand101 Is `WhereIterable` not a subtype of `Iterable` and is `List` not a subtype of `Iterable`?

Comment: Yes? `WhereIterable` is a `Iterable` and so are `List`. But you cannot say a `Iterable` is a `List`.

Comment: @julemand101 We can also not say that an `Object` is a `String` but we can surely use `as String` and it works for the `Object`, right?

Comment: No? If you have a `int` which are a `Object` you cannot just say `as String` and expect things to work that way...

Comment: `Object o = 'Foo'`, and any method expecting `String` in parameter would allow `o as String` to work, you're taking `int` example which is completely different thing here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219751/discussion-between-julemand101-and-iloveflutterdocs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`where` returns a `Iterable` (on runtime in your case it is `WhereIterable` which implements the `Iterable` interface). Your problem is that you cannot say that all `Iterable` is a `List` but you can say that all `List` objects are also `Iterable` since `List` implements the `Iterable` interface.

So your typecast with `as List<int>` fails since Dart checks typecasts on runtime and it can tell that `WhereIterable` is not compatible with the `List` interface.

`toList()` works since this is documented as:

> Creates a List containing the elements of this Iterable.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html

So this method will return a new `List` containing all the elements from the returned `WhereIterable` since it has gone through all the elements returned from the `Iterable` and created a fresh new `List` object with the elements.